# Finding the mean of a group, based on the most recent date of each group

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, shiny, shinyapps

Sorry for the unclear title.
The question I have is simple but difficult to articulate.
If I have the sample data set:

| Person | Date (m/d/y) | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | 01/15/21 | 93 |
| Person2 | 01/16/21 | 87 |
| Person3 | 01/14/21 | 73 |
| Person1 | 01/17/21 | 95 |
| Person2 | 01/15/21 | 85 |
| Person3 | 01/18/21 | 73.5 |

In R how do I find the average of Person1,2,3 weights. Keeping in mind I only their most recent weight is important.

Therefore, the correct answer should be:

- Person1 (01/17/21) weight = 95;
- Person2 (01/16/21) weight = 87;
- Person3 (01/18/21) weight = 73.5;

Mean = 85.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to do a group by `slice` on the last date and then take the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.Date(`Date (m/d/y)`, '%m/%d/%y'))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  summarise(Weight = mean(Weight, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  Weight
#   <dbl>
#1   85.2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Person = c("Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person1", 
"Person2", "Person3"), `Date (m/d/y)` = c("01/15/21", "01/16/21", 
"01/14/21", "01/17/21", "01/15/21", "01/18/21"), Weight = c(93, 
87, 73, 95, 85, 73.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you! This should work great! May I ask a follow up question:
This small problem has happened many times when I am coding but when I write code like you have above R Shiny can not find the variable I reference. In order to fix this I have to write... 
'''
    df1 %>%
    group_by(df1$Person) %>%
    slice(which.max(as.Date(df1$'Date (m/d/y)', '%m/%d/%y'))) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    summarise (Weight = mean (Weight))
'''

Even in the above example, I get an error where R can not find Weight.

Comment: @ZacharyMcClean sure, go ahead

Comment: Warning: Error in : Problem with `summarise()` input `Weight`.
x object 'Weight' not found
ℹ Input `Weight` is `mean(Weight)`

Comment: @ZacharyMcClean You don't need to use `df1$` inside.  Also, use backquote instead of single or double quotes

Comment: perhaps it is important to know that my data is currently in the form of a data table. I not sure if this is an issue

Comment: @ZacharyMcClean If you look at my solution, I didn't use `df1$` inside tthe tidyverse

Comment: This is my issue, if I do not include df$ inside, then R will not find the variables in question.

Comment: @ZacharyMcClean you don't need `df$` inside tidyverse.  The issue is that your column name is non-specific ie. have space etc.  So you need backquotes as in my post

Comment: @ZacharyMcClean Can you please copy/paste my solution and see if there is any errors

Comment: @ZacharyMcClean `group_by(df1$Person)` is wrong because it expects a unquoted column name instead of the value of that column

Comment: Okay thank you this solved the problem (sorry about the confusion)...  I just realized there is an issue in my data where I have some NA values, is there a way to add to the code and ignore the NAs?

Comment: @ZacharyMcClean Is it for the `Weight` column, then use `mean(Weight, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you very much, That was extremely helpful.. not only for this specific question but also for expanding my R knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  Weight[which.max(as.Date(`Date (m/d/y)`, format = "%m/%d/%y"))],
  Person
][
  ,
  mean(V1)
]
```

gives

```
[1] 85.16667
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Person = c("Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person1",
"Person2", "Person3"), `Date (m/d/y)` = c("01/15/21", "01/16/21",
"01/14/21", "01/17/21", "01/15/21", "01/18/21"), Weight = c(93,
87, 73, 95, 85, 73.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```